# finding edges of a triangle graph from degrees of points

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, triangulation

my theory: Given a list of points on a 2 dimensional plane, and the degree of each point, there should correspond only one way to arrange the edges between points so that the final graph is a mesh of only triangles, and the degree of every point is correct.

MY question is, is my theory true, and if so, if there is a way to find the unique graph given just the degrees of each point?(might be very difficult)

I know my theory isn't very formal, I'll try to clarify as much as possible if needed. I wasn't sure of the correct terminology, but what I mean by a triangle mesh is something like this  [example of graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Delaunay_Triangulation_(100_Points).svg/2000px-Delaunay_Triangulation_(100_Points).svg.png)

Comment: are you requiring that the edges are straight? I am assuming so, but as that condition is not usually necessary for graphs, it is worth noting.

Comment: also, are you requiring the outer region to be a triangle? if that is the case, there are many arrangements that will not yield any solution.

Comment: In this case I'm only interested in arrangements with a solution. And yes only straight edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, here's a counterexample:

[image: counterexample]

Comment: Interesting. Do you think that it is significant that the counterexample is a reflection of the original? The application I'd be using it for wouldn't have 'orderly' graphs like this, for lack of me remembering the proper term, and I'm still interested in my theory. Thanks for your time regardless.

Comment: You could take a point and move it a small amount, then the two solutions won't be reflections of each other.  Or you could add another point to the right, and connect it to the three rightmost vertices.  It may be significant that the graphs are isomorphic though - I wasn't able to find a counterexample where they weren't.